# Hidden Table Re-appears After Save, Close, Open

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word document with a table at the top of the first page that I want to hide by default (it contains maintenance information and notes that doesn't always need to be shown).

If I select the table, click font, and check hidden, the table hides as expected when I click the show/hide button. However, if I save and close the document, the border for this table appears at the top of the page.

Any ideas why that might be happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: What version of Word document are you saving as, e.g DOC, DOCX and what version of Word are you using?

Comment: It's a .docx file opened with Word 2010.

Comment: have you tried highlighting the entire table and setting it to hidden again to see if that fixes it?